# Goal ordering in Clojure's `core.logic`

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic

[The following Clojure code](https://gist.github.com/4525736) uses `core.logic` to solve the same logic problem with the same goals in two different orders.  This choice of ordering causes one to finish quickly and the other to hang.

```
(use `clojure.core.logic)

;; Runs quickly.  Prints (1 2 3).
(clojure.pprint/pprint (run* [q] (fresh [x] (== x [1,2,3]) 
                                            (membero q x))))

;; Hangs
(clojure.pprint/pprint (run* [q] (fresh [x] (membero q x) 
                                            (== x [1,2,3]))))
```

Is there a general solution or common practice to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use `membero` there is no general solution to this problem. Calling `membero` with fresh vars will cause it to generate all (read, infinite) possible lists for which `q` is a member.  Of course lists larger than 3 don't apply - but since you've used `run*` it will continue blindly trying lists larger than count 3 even though each one will fail.

It's possible to write a better version of `membero` in newer versions of core.logic using the constraint infrastructure, but the details of how one might do this are likely to change over the coming months. Until there's a solid public api for defining constraints you're stuck with the kind of subtle ordering and non-termination issues that trouble Prolog.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my understanding:

With `core.logic`, you want to reduce the search space as early as possible. If you put the `membero` constraint first, the run will start by searching the `membero` space, and backtrack on failure produced by the `==` constraint. But the `membero` space is HUGE, since neither `q` nor `x` is unified or at least bounded.

But if you put the `==` constraint first, you directly unify `x` with `[1 2 3]`, and the search space for `membero` now is clearly bounded to the elements of `x`.

Comment: What exactly is it searching in `(membero q x)`?  Is x actually iterating among all possible collections?  What computations are occuring while it hangs?

Comment: @MRocklin, exactly. In fact, if you imagine the code for `membero`, it will try to unify the element with a list with just that element, and then recursively build lists that contain the element at any position till infinite. In theory, the ordering of facts is not needed, but is convenient to limit the search tree.