# Non-termination when query variable is on a specific position

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

Consider [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/07/logic-programming-clojure-palindromes/) where the author implements palindrome relation using `reverso`:

```
(defn reverso [l r]
  (conde
    [(== l ()) (== r ())]
    [(fresh [la ld ldr]
      (conso la ld l)
      (appendo ldr (list la) r)
      (reverso ld ldr))]))
```

When I run `(run* [q] (reverso q [1 2 3]))`, the output is `([3 2 1])`. However, when I run `(run* [q] (reverso [1 2 3] q))`, the program does not terminate. I am able to get the correct result by explicitly requesting one result via `run 1`.

When experimenting, I was able to implement the same function myself using `defne`:

```
(defne conjo2 [l a la]
       ([[] _ [a]])
       ([[c . bs] _ [c . cs]] (conjo2 bs a cs)))

(defne reverso [l r]
       ([[] []])
       ([[a . ls] _]
        (fresh [rs]
               (conjo2 rs a r)
               (reverso ls rs))))
```

but the same issue is present. However, if I change my custom `conjo2` to `core.logic/conjo`, the position of the variable during non-termination changes.

- Why does the program not terminate for the general query with specific locations of the query variable?
- Why specifying `run 1` succeeds, but as soon as `run 2` the program does not terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you give `appendo` a fresh variable on the left and a fresh variable for the result, it can produce arbitrarily many answers, none of which will lead to a solution for your overall `reverso` question. Witness [the definition of `appendo`](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/01c0310b0dc4fd3e402bd4dabf5579322a935416/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj#L1780):

```
(defne appendo
  "A relation where x, y, and z are proper collections,
  such that z is x appended to y"
  [x y z]
  ([() _ y])
  ([[a . d] _ [a . r]] (appendo d y r)))
```

It terminates if the `x` argument is empty (succeeding with `y` as the result); otherwise, it assumes that both `x` and the result `z` are non-empty lists and calls itself recursively. This terminates if either `x` or `z` can be proven to have a finite length, or if an index they share has a different value in the two lists. You never impose either of those constraints, so it continues searching forever.

Let's step through the execution of a simpler query, `(run 2 [q] (reverso [1] q))`.

1. We test whether `l` and `r` are both empty
2. They're not, so we fresh up some variables and assert that `(conso la ld [1])`

   1. This succeeds, binding `(== la 1)` and `(== ld [])`.
3. Next we assert that `(appendo ldr [1] r)`.

   1. This succeeds via the first clause in `appendo`, binding `(== ldr [])` and `(== r [1])`.
4. We recurse into `(reverso [] [])`, and check whether both arguments are empty.

   1. This succeeds, so we yield our first overall result: `(== q [1])` (remember that at the outer level `(== q r)`, so a solution for `r` is a solution for `q`).
   2. We've been asked for more results, so we keep searching, which means rejecting the clause that just succeeded to see if alternatives might yield additional successes.

      1. Rejecting 4.1 is a quick dead end: we have `(== l [])` at this point, so the `conso` fails.
      2. Now we backtrack to 3.1, the empty-list clause in `(appendo ldr [1] r)`. Rejecting this puts us in the second clause, `(appendo d [1] r1)`, binding `(== ldr [a . d])` and `(== r1 [a . r])`.

You can see this will never lead anywhere: the lists we're looking through are longer than the list we're trying to reverse. But before it can fail, it will make another recursive call to `reverso`, which will make a call to `appendo`, which will lengthen the lists again and make a recursive call to `reverso`, and so on. This is a simlar problem to that described in [Goal ordering in Clojure's `core.logic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307187/625403).

You can fix this by first informing the engine that you expect the two lists to be the same length. Then attempts by `appendo` to lengthen its input and output beyond the limit will fail. First, define `same-lengtho`:

```
(defn same-lengtho [xs ys]
  (conde
   [(== xs ()) (== ys ())]
   [(fresh [x xs' y ys']
      (conso x xs' xs)
      (conso y ys' ys)
      (same-lengtho xs' ys'))]))
```

Then insert a call to `same-lengtho` before you start the main search<sup>1</sup>:

```
(defn reverso* [l r]
  (conde
   [(== l ()) (== r ())]
   [(fresh [la ld ldr]
      (conso la ld l)
      (appendo ldr (list la) r)
      (reverso* ld ldr))]))

(defn reverso [l r]
  (all (same-lengtho l r)
       (reverso* l r)))
```

Defined as such, a `run*` query produces the correct results regardless of parameter order:

```
user=> (run* [q] (reverso q [1 2 3]))
((3 2 1))
user=> (run* [q] (reverso [1 2 3] q))
((3 2 1))
```

And just to show that we haven't accidentally done something one-directional with `same-lengtho`, observe that with totally fresh variables on both sides it still generates all possible lists and their reverses:

```
user=> (run 5 [a b] (reverso a b))
([() ()]
 [(_0) (_0)]
 [(_0 _1) (_1 _0)] 
 [(_0 _1 _2) (_2 _1 _0)] 
 [(_0 _1 _2 _3) (_3 _2 _1 _0)])
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You don't technically need both `(== l ())` and `(== r ())` anymore: either one will suffice since you pre-guaranteed that the lists are the same length. But to me it seems semantically nicer to leave in the redundant check.